# How to use a filter or import parameter: if_http_extension handle_request

Tags: abap, netweaver

I'm working on a project where we need to build a REST service but we can't use SAP Gateway. I'm using SICF and classes to create services like this guide: [1](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/01/24/developing-a-rest-api-in-abap/#jive_content_id_First_Strategy_HTTP_Request_Method)

The thing I don't understand is how to use filters or import parameters for a GET request for example. Can anyone help me on my way, please?

Comment: did my answer help? if yes, accept it.

Comment: I'm looking into it. I will as soon as I'm able to test it. Thanks so much for your input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is possible if you work with HTTP header variables.

Check this: https://blogs.sap.com/2011/04/07/deliver-dynamic-search-of-sap-data-into-a-website-using-restful-services/ or this https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/865718

In abap you read it via (path_info = your variable name):

```
path_info = server->request->get_header_field( name = ‘~path_info’ ).
```

If you don't get it running please provide some information on your GET request as well as your method for receiving the request.

Edit: acc. to this you might use a POST instead of a GET. I think your parameter is correct (it is the only way if you dont post a body) archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3801491

GL, zYrEx

Comment: I tried it like this: http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:YYYY/fioriapp/notification?id=500 with PATH_INFO = SERVER->REQUEST->GET_HEADER_FIELD( '~id' ). It returns empty somehow. Should I add a parameter id somewhere?

Comment: acc. to this you might use a POST instead of a GET? I think your parameter is correct (it is the only way if you dont post a body) https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3801491

Comment: I tried it like that and it works. Maybe you can edit your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: DATA: FIELDS      TYPE TIHTTPNVP.

    SERVER->REQUEST->GET_FORM_FIELDS(
    CHANGING
      FIELDS = FIELDS
      ).

Comment: thanks! btw. think about using SAP NetWeaver Gateway to get this topic future proof ;-) I edited my answer.